# Questions about restriction group representations, thanks!

Tags: representation-theory

I am studying group representation theory, and I have trouble understanding the restriction group representations. Could someone help me to answer the following questions?

1. Intuitively, if a group representation $\phi$ is irreducible, then the restricted representation $\phi|_H$  is irreducible. However, this is NOT the general case. The general case is actually restricted representation is irreducible would imply the group representation is irreducible. Could someone help me to understand or prove this relation?
2. Also, could someone give me an example such that if a group representation $\phi$ is irreducible, then, $\phi|_H$  is NOT irreducible?
3. Could someone help me to solve a more practical problem. Say, let $\phi$ be natural representation of $S_4$ , Then how can I decompose the representation $\phi$ restricted on $S_3$ into irreducible components？

Thank you all for helping me in advance!

Comment: The word "Intuitively" in 1 bears witness of bad intuition. If $H$ is the trivial subgroup, then the restriction of $\phi\mid_H$ will be just a $\dim\phi$-dimensional vector subspace (since representations of the trivial group are just "dumb" vector spaces), and thus won't be irreducible unless $\phi$ happens to be $1$-dimensional. This should also answer question 2.

Comment: For question 3, you are looking for what is called a "branching rule from $S_4$ to $S_3$". Generally, branching rules for $S_{n+1}$ to $S_n$ are known for all $n$, and on the abstract side look really nice: The irreducible representations of $S_n$ are indexed by Young diagrams of size $n$. When you restrict to $S_n$ an irreducible representation of $S_{n+1}$ corresponding to some Young diagram $\lambda$ (of size $n+1$), then you obtain the direct sum of the irreducible representations of $S_n$ corresponding to all Young diagrams obtained ...

Comment: ... from $\lambda$ by removing a single box. (And each of these representations appears only once.) Of course, this just tells you what representations you will find, but not how/where to find them. The latter is much more interesting, and I don't have a quick answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! that's really helpful! I am also looking for a proof of the statement "restricted representation irreducible will imply representation irreducible " Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: That statement is quite simple: If the representation $V$ has a subrepresentation $W$, then $W\mid_H$ is a subrepresentation of $V\mid_H$.

Comment: Right now I'm not sure if I'm getting something wrong but if a restricted representation is irreducible then this does *not* imply that the *big* representation of the *big* group is irreducible.

Comment: @darij grinberg thank you! I see!